# How to access the parameters in the current url in the backend express function? (see description)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, ejs

Alright so I can't figure out how to explain this. Basically I am writing a simple express app that requests the omdb api to search for a movie title and return the results. Now the omdb api send back the results as pages with 10 results per page.

This is my app.js file

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let request = require("request");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

let query = "";
let page = 1;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("search");
});

app.get("/results", (req, res) => {
    if(req.query.search){
        query = req.query.search;
    }
    if(req.query.page){
        page = req.query.page;
    }else{
        page = 1;
    }
    console.log(query);
    console.log(page);
    let url = "http://omdbapi.com/?apikey=thewdb&s=" + query + "&page=" + page;
    request(url, (error, response, body) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            let data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("results", {data: data});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, () => {
    console.log("Server Started");
});
```

This is my search.ejs file

```
<h1>Search for a Movie</h1>

<form action="/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And this is my results.ejs file

```
<h1>Results of Search</h1>

<ul>
    <% data["Search"].forEach((movie) => { %>
        <li> 
            <strong><%= movie["Title"] %></strong> - <%= movie["Year"] %> 
        </li>
    <% }); %>
</ul>

<form action="/results" method=GET>
    <input type="text" name="page" placeholder="Page">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<a href="/">Search Again</a>
```

This works where the user can type the page number in the results page and go to the next page. However, what happens is when I send back the page number, the search query is lost. Right now my solution is to define a global variable and keep track of the query like that, but is there a proper way to do this?

I have recently started learning backend development so I am very new to express and node.

Comment: That's when I call the /results function from inside the /search page. If I go the /results function from inside the results page itself when i submit the page number then I don't have any search query.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now my solution is to define a global variable and keep track of the query like that

Don't do that.

You'll get race conditions. And cross-user pollution.

---

Just put the query in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="query" value="...">
```

Comment: But how do I access the value of the search query from inside the result page to put in as the value of the hidden form?

Comment: The same way you access `data["Search"]`

Comment: So data["Search"] is from the json data sent back from the omdb api. But by search query I mean the search term the user enters on the search page.
http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=thewdb&s=florida. This link is for the JSON data that omdb returns and this is where data["Search"] comes from. But what i want is the original search term the user entered in the seach page.

Comment: @abdullahaquarius — It doesn't matter where `data["Search"]` came from. You have a variable in your server side code. You rendered the template with it. You already have a variable in your server side code for your query. Render the template with that too.